# FormatException on Convert.FromBase64String c#

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, base64, formatexception

On a Windows CE device using the .NET CF. I'm receiving a big file (12MB) over a stream from a REST service.

This big file is in base64 format, but it has two small details, the content surrounded by double quotes (`"`) and every N characters there's a `\\n` (not the line break character `\n`, but the actual 2 literal characters).
So what I need to do is, remove the quotes and also the `\\n` or replace them with the actual line break. And also convert from the base64 format.

This is the code that I have:

```
var input = ApplicationContext.restProxy.GetData();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input))
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] buffer = new char[32];
    while (sr.Read(buffer, 0, 32) > 0)
    {
       var s = new string(buffer);
       s = s.Replace("\\n", "\n");
       s = s.Trim('"');
       sb.Append(s);
    }

    byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sb.ToString());

}
```

But with this code I either have a `OutOfMemoryException`, or a `FormatException` when I call the `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Some input data has the following format:

```
"U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzAAQAAQEAQCAgAAAABAAAI2oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAA\\nAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAC3iGgUAAAABA/sAAAAaSQP7\\nApsA0wDTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ...
```

How can I do these operations without filling up the memory of the device, or what is wrong with the format of the resulting string?

Comment: An obvious failure mode of your code is that the Read() call returns `\\` but not yet the n.  Fixing that will increase the odds you run out of memory.  Few ways to win here, send a nasty email to the service owner to make yourself feel better, I guess.

Comment: That `FormatException` you get is because last `sr.Read` will return incomplete buffer (less then 32 bytes), but you append all 32 in `sb.Append(s)`. You should use another `Append` overload that has `count` param.

Comment: Why would you read binary data from a `TextReader`?

Comment: @leppie, where is the TextReader being used? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @ohvitorino: `StreamReader` derives from `TextReader`

Answer (score 1):

You could get better results if you write to a buffer that checks character by character.

Also, since the file is so large, you may get better results by writing this data directly to an output file. Otherwise, you are trying to hold all of this data in memory.

Sending the output directly to a file may get you around this problem, but I don't know. I've never encountered it, so I don't know how to test it.

Here is a sample method that may take care of your problems:

```
private void ReadData(Stream input) {
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input)) {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create("outfile.dat"))) {
      char[] buffer = new char[32];
      while (-1 < sr.Peek()) {
        int len = sr.Read(buffer, 0, 32);
        List<char> output = new List<char>();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          char c = buffer[i];
          if ((c != '\\') && (c != '\n')) {
            output.Add(c);
          }
        }
        sw.Write(output.ToArray());
      }
      sw.Flush();
      sw.Close();
    }
    sr.Close();
  }
}
```

Though `Close()` is not required, I found it helps in situations where you could be calling a certain method many times before the Garbage Collector has a chance to clean things up for you. It's better to be safe.

I hope it provides some use.

Comment: You make a good suggestion. And it can be an option to write it directly to a file. But after that I have to reopen the file and convert the full content from base64 to binary. So that is why I was trying the approach that would do that beforehand.